# In cnosdb, why can a nonexistent database execute sql?

Tags: cnosdb

I log into cnosdb with a database that doesn't exist

```
./target/debug/cnosdb-cli --database no_exists_db
```

and I find that I can still execute sql normally
[image]

which is different from my understanding. Any comments on this?

Comment: I think you’re asking why doesn’t it explicitly say the DB doesn’t exist and error. Many DBs have other tables (as you can see) and they’re always there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal, and when the database parameter does not affect the overall sql logic, there is no problem